# Does ranges::lower_bound have different requirements for the comparison than std::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, c++20

It seems that using the same comparison functor that worked fine with std::lower_bound() does not work with std::ranges::lower_bound() in C++20. The following code does not compile with either Visual Studio 16.10.2 (and /std::c++latest) or gcc 11.1. I can work around the issue by using a projection instead of a comparison functor, but that increases the effort for migration.

Are the requirements for the argument "comp" in std::ranges::lower_bound() different from std::lower_bound(), and if so, how?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    double m_value;
};

struct MyComparison {
    bool operator()(const A& a, const double& b) {
        return a.m_value < b;
    }
};

void f() {
    std::vector<A> v = {A{1.0}, A{2.0}, A{3.0}};

    // comparison functor without ranges compiles as expected:
    auto x = std::lower_bound(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 2.0, MyComparison());

    // projection with ranges compiles as expected:
    auto y = std::ranges::lower_bound(v, 2.0, {}, &A::m_value);

    // comparison functor with ranges fails to compile:
    auto z = std::ranges::lower_bound(v, 2.0, MyComparison());
}
```

Error messages in Visual Studio:
error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
error C7602: 'std::ranges::_Lower_bound_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is.

`std::ranges::lower_bound`'s `Comp` must be

```
std::indirect_strict_weak_order<const double*, std::vector<A>::iterator>
```

which expands to lots of variations of

```
std::strict_weak_order<Comp&, const double&, A&>
```

which expand to

```
std::predicate<Comp&, const double&, const double&> &&
std::predicate<Comp&, const double&, A&> &&
std::predicate<Comp&, A&,            const double&> &&
std::predicate<Comp&, A&,            A&>
```

So you need to be able to handle every permutation of parameter types.

`std::lower_bound`'s `Comp` only needs to be *Compare*, which is fine with just the `(A&, const double&)` form.

Comment: If, instead of using a custom Comparator, we were to define the `<=>` spaceship operator for `A` and use the syntax `auto z = std::ranges::lower_bound(v, A(2.0));`, would it work? I can't seem to make it work in my project. I may be missing something.

Comment: @Telokis If you construct an `A` you only need `<`

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the projection to transform your `A` struct into the comparison value.

```
auto lb = std::ranges::lower_bound( v, 2.0,
         []( double m_value, double rng ) { return rng < m_value; }, //comparison predicate using doubles
         []( auto const& myA ) { return myA.m_value; } ); //projection that converts from a A to a double. This projection should return the type used in the predicate comparison
```

Comment: Or `std::ranges::lower_bound( v, 2.0, std::less<>{}, &A::m_value );`

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up on the answers from @caleth and @scott-nykl, if you don't want to use a projection (for instance if you want to reuse the predicate), you could also alter the predicate as follows:

```
struct MyComparison {
    static constexpr const auto& get(const double& d) { return d; };
    static constexpr const auto& get(const A& a) { return a.m_value; }
    auto operator()(const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return get(lhs) < get(rhs);
    }
};
```

Comment: You may want to have `get` return by reference otherwise you'll get a lot of copies.